# remove first image with interval

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using...

```
[self addChild:self.blue_action];
[self schedule:@selector(updateTimer1:) interval:1.0f];
```

Via this line, I want to show an image in the any position and after some time that image will remove, through '[self removeChild: self.blue_action cleanUp:Yes];'

```
-(void)updateTimer1:(id)sender {
    if(time_1 == 0) {
        NSLog(@"time value ");
        [self removeChild:self.blue_action cleanup:YES];
        [self schedule: @selector(updateTimer1:) interval:0.10];
    }
    else {
        --time_1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `updateTimer1:(id)sender` method was already scheduled.
To schedule this again you obvious must unscheduled this method by  `[self unschedule:_cmd];`

And it's a good practice do not remove sprite every time when you want it to disappear, try to just make it invisible  `self.blue_action.visible = NO`

Answer (score 0):

You want to fire method once after specific time? Action is helpful.

```
-(void)addBlueAction {
    [self addChild:self.blue_action];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
        [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self
            selector:@selector(removeBlueAction)],
        nil]];
}

-(void)removeBlueAction {
    [self removeChild:self.blue_action cleanup:YES];
}
```

If your app's target is for after iOS 4.0, you can use Blocks.

```
-(void)addBlueAction {
    [self addChild:self.blue_action];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
        [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
        [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

            [self removeChild:self.blue_action cleanup:YES];

        }],
        nil]];
}
```